# Why is Evey's name so fitting to V?

Tags: v-for-vendetta

In the first meeting of V and Evey in *V for Vendetta*, V finds Evey's name very fitting. Why?

It's not evident from the dialogue:

> V: But to whom, may I ask, am I speaking?
>   E: I'm Evey.
>   V: Evey? E. V. Of course you are.
>   E: What does that mean?
>   V: It means that I, like God, do not play with dice and do not believe in coincidence.

[image]

Comment: may be because it's similar to "i v"

Comment: I don't think there's anything more to it than what @madmada said. Perhaps only the fact that by saying "of course  you are", he establishes himself as the dominant personality in the interaction. But really, it's due to similarities to v.

Comment: Just to take it a step further there is a lot of symbolism in V for Vendetta. V states that he does not believe in coincidence because symbolically Evey is V. And we are V as well. This is why everyone is wearing the same face, the same mask of V. Because we are V, we are one.

Comment: @EKenny: Great point. Enough to be converted to an answer.

Comment: ... plus E is the fifth letter of the alphabet and V is the roman numeral for 5 helps too I guess!

Comment: I would reason that her name is both characters "EV" whereas his name is "V", meaning he is half of her, whereas she is both halves, and thus the one to live on.

Answer (score 8):

There is a lot of symbolism in V for Vendetta. V states that he does not believe in coincidence because symbolically Evey is V. And we are V as well. This is why everyone is wearing the same face, the same mask of V. Because we are V, we are one.

There are subtle hints to this throughout the film for example in the opening scene Evey and V 'mirror' each other. Both characters are doing the same things: Applying their ‘face’, watching TV and putting on their costume.

Answer (score 3):

Take this hint and listen to the movie again. V is 5 in roman numbers. E is the fifth letter of the alphabet. 5th of november. 55 V words in the classic monologue. Techaikowski. A lot of fun stuff to analyse ;)

Comment: I didn't get the point with Techaikowski, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

e can be used for the french verb "essere" which translates to "to be" so "e-vey" ="to be V" or simply "being V". Because we are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is a little more subtle. V is fond of Latin phrases and speaks a few lines in the movie. The phonetic pronunciation of Evey's name is 'E V' In Latin, E means 'from'. Her name, in Latin using only the phonetic pronunciation, literally means 'From V."

Answer (score -1):

If you pay attention to the last part when she asked the detective after he let her send the train
"tell me detective, you like music?" just like V had asked her after she just told V her name..so as madmada said V thinks of her as next V or another V when she said her name Evey — I V